# apt remove a package but keep autoinstalled packages

Tags: apt

On my Debian server some packages were not explicitely installed, but where automatically installed when installing another package.

After some time, I started using some of those packages now in different contexts.

Now If I try to remove the initially installed package, apt suggests to also uninstall all the autoinstalled packages, which I still need by now.

How do I uninstall **only** the package without uninstaling the autoinstalled packages too?

Comment: Related: [How to exclude a package from apt-get autoremove?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943289/how-to-exclude-a-package-from-apt-get-autoremove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `dpkg -r` to remove a package only .

Answer (score 2):

When you start needing a package on its own merits, rather than as a dependency, you need to tell `apt` that fact. [There are two ways of doing so](https://askubuntu.com/q/943289/412264):

- explicitly installing an already-installed package, with `apt install`, won’t install it again, but will mark it as manually installed (and upgrade it if the version in the repositories is newer than the installed version);
- marking a package, with `apt-mark manual`.

Either of these will set the package as manually installed, and it will stop being a candidate for auto-removal.

Note that “auto-removal” is a bit of a misnomer: in its default configuration, `apt` never removes packages automatically unless it has to for dependency reasons. Auto-removable packages are only removed if `apt` is explicitly told to do so. Aptitude, on the other hand, does remove auto-removable packages on its own.